# postfix dovecot avoid duplicate sendings from two different IPs but same computer, same sender/recipients, same subject & body

Tags: postfix, dovecot, deduplication

Is there a way to avoid duplicate sendings from two different IPs but same computer, same sender, same recipients, same subject & body ?
I'm using a postfix/dovecot server to which one of the clients connects using two concurrent internet connections with macOS Apple Mail application.

I would like to avoid exclusion of one of the IPs or reverse DNS, because other people could be using it, and the client sometimes uses only one of these connections, because his network is sometimes unstable.
Though this hasbeen dealt with at the source by disabling one of the network connections, I think it could be a better security for the mail server reputation to script something in order to avoid this kind of duplicate sending.

Would it be possible to temporize the sending and check for duplicate subject, body, recipients and sender ?

Comment: Are you trying to say that the sender is sending the same message more than once?

Comment: He sends once but due to the network, sometimes it sends twice.

Comment: This has been dealt with at the source, but I thought it would be a better security for the mail server reputation to script something for this kind of issue...